# 'range' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't understand why python gives me the above error!!

```
def my_function(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x
print (my_function(range(3)))
```

Comment: Well what is the supposed output?

Comment: `my_function(list(range(3)))`

Comment: An iterator is not an array, you should read the docs.

Comment: `range(..)` does **not construct a list**. It constructs a `range` object.

Comment: @user3467349 and a list is not an array, and range is not an iterator...